# Manga about a main character who is reborn as a noble child and ends up causing the death of his mother, because she gave birth

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

The main character was reincarnated as a baby into a noble family and he was the youngest. After the mother gave birth, she started to become weak and ended up passing away. Then one of the siblings tried to kill the baby, but failed.

The attempt on the baby failed because I think it was the uncle or another family member that blocked the attack and the sibling who tried to kill the baby was sent away to another place to live to prevent another attack from happening. I also remember the main character is adored by everyone in the family and is gifted at magic

Comment: Was this in full colour and what colour was the MC's hair?

Comment: The manga is in black and white and the mc hair is white in the manga if I remember correctly

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the attempt at killing the baby failed? Was he able to run away immediately after being born, or fly with his magic powers or something similar? Do you remember anything else that happens in the story?

Comment: The attempt on the baby failed because I think it was the uncle or another family member that blocked the attack and the sibiling who tried to kill the baby was sent away to another place to live to prevent another attack from happening and what else I remember from the story is not much but he is adored by everyone in the family and is gifted at magic

Answer (score 1):

[Fuun kara no Saikyou Otoko](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=197164) ("Unluckiness to the Strongest Man"):

> (Bad luck and Good luck are like two sides of the same coin!? Defy the misfortune!)
>
> Siegbert reincarnated after an accident because of his bad luck. His new family is so warm that he can’t believe that his past life was a stroke of bad luck. In this life, he thought he would be able to spend his peaceful life… but he holds unbelievable [luck value]…?
>
> (Good luck attracts opportunity. If you can seize it, your wish will come true!)
>
> The family and others are in desperate, after strong enemy (chance) one by one stand in the way!? No, I will hold it with my extraordinary magic power and appraisal eyes. (seize it)
>
> From “Shousetsuka ni Narou” A heroic tale of a boy who becomes the strongest to protect his warm family! Also includes a newly written novel from the original author.

Comment: only 7 Ch in English's

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how this matches the story described in the question?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a match according to the description I found, which says MC's "new family is so warm" (which would seem to be at odds with them trying to kill him).